# jQuery form generation

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, forms

I'm basically looking for the client-side equivalent of Django's ModelForm: I want to be able to specify the general schema of my data (what the fields are, which ones are required, what kinds of fields to use, etc.), and I want to be able to dynamically generate the form, itself, fill it with any initial data, validate it, and extract an object containing the validated data that I can Ajaxily submit places when the form has been filled out.

Dos this exist?  Something jQuery-flavored would be preferred.

Comment: Interesting concept, but why would you want it all generated on the client side?  You'll lose degradation.

Comment: Why would you want to be with jquery?

Comment: Who cares about degradation? This is 2010. And being that it _is_ 2010, you can generate your html from ssjs, should needs be.

Comment: The target application is a CouchDB-hosted app, so Javascript will be a hard requirement; Couch really doesn't offer much in the way of server-side processing, so CouchApps are pretty much by definition all client-side, and don't degrade gracefully.  We're willing to live with that for our use case.

As for jQuery, it's the stack with which I'm most familiar, and jQuery UI will probably play a role elsewhere in the app, so a jQuery-based solution would be convenient.

Comment: Well, you could hook the CouchDB up to Node.js this would let you run YUI serverside as well and have it render yui widgets to HTML, but, yeah :)

Answer (score 3):

You might also check out Alpaca (http://www.alpacajs.org).  It's similar in some ways to Joshfire's JSON Form library.  It uses JSON Schema and features a JSON-based way of specifying your layout and additional rendering options.  It also uses templates for flexibility.

You can register your own controls for different data types.  It comes with a whole bunch of controls already defined for things like simple text entry all the way to Google Maps and more.

Best of all, it's open-source and based on jQuery.  It's been around for the better part of two years and we've been using it with Cloud CMS at my company.  (disclaimer: I'm biased + I haven't tried any of the other tools suggested, they're likely awesome as well)

Answer (score 0):

http://neyric.github.com/inputex/examples/json-schema.html
This is very likely what you want. Give YUI a whirl ;)

Answer (score 0):

May I also humbly suggest [Metawidget](http://metawidget.org)? It supports a broad range of back-end definitions and UI frameworks.

Answer (score -1):

Joshfire's [JSON Form library](http://developer.joshfire.com/doc/dev/ref/jsonform) does just that.

It uses the IETF standard JSON Schema format to describe your models, and it can validate your data against it using [JSV](https://github.com/garycourt/JSV).

It lets you specify the form layout, but it generates a default form if you don't.

It's based on JQuery.

Comment: Link to JSON Form Library doesn't exist